# How to close a PDF file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, pdf

I have been working on **[Vanilla](http://github.com/adhithyan15/vanilla)**, a LaTex preprocessor. I and most people open their PDF files to see how their output looks like. But sometimes, we forget to close it down before starting the compiling process again. If the PDF file is open, then the LaTex compiler complains that it cannot write to that file. So I want to add code to the preprocessor which will look if the output PDF file is open and it will close the PDF file if it is open. I have been looking everywhere to see how to go about doing it. I am not an expert in Ruby. **I don't want to kill the whole process of Acrobat32.exe or any other PDF viewing program used to view that file because the user might have other PDFs open in the same program.** I just need a way to kill the process of that one PDF file. So can anyone suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just move the old file first, remove it if possible, and then generate a new version of the same PDF with the name you want?

Comment: How do you move or delete a file which is open?

Comment: It depends on your OS, but often you can move a file but not delete it if it's still open. As an alternative you could render out to a different filename each time.